# Securing Solr page in SolrCloud configuration

Tags: security, solr

In my environment I have Solr 6.2 running in Cloud mode where I am trying to secure the Solr Admin UI and found couple of article that explains how to achieve it,

1. https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/securing-solr.html
2. http://muddyazian.blogspot.in/2013/11/how-to-require-password-authentication.html

My understanding is that securing through Jetty will work only on the standalone deployments and not in the SolrCloud deployments.

Is that right?

Comment: Your first link shows how to do it using Solr's own capabilities. What's the problem with those? (.. and the first step in securing Solr is to not expose it to the public internet)

Comment: I am not sure whether securing the admin page through Jetty will work in SolrCloud configuration as well?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to do it on the jetty level - which would not be easily synced across your nodes if anything changes, or is something that would have to be maintained separately for any upgrades being performed on Solr - when Solr has both authentication and authorization built-in now.

Comment: Totally agree with you MatsLindh. After further investigation event i decided to go with Solr's built-in authentication and authorization. Thanks for the feedback.